# sql select rows with duplicate data

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with this select statement in my relational table
(both supplier and products are composite primary key which uniquely identified each rows

```
Supplier    Products
ABC         Toys
ABC         Snacks
ZXC         Snacks
ZXC         Food
QWE         Toys
ABC         Food
```

I need to find the supplier that does not supply toys
so i shoud only get ZXC

I try the following but it give me ABC, ZXC

```
select distinct Supplier
from table 
where NOT (Products ='Toys');
```

(I am using oracle) how should my query be? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
select distinct supplier 
from table
where supplier not in (select supplier from table where products = 'Toys')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `group by` `Supplier`  and use `having` clause evaluated to true if conditional count is equal to 0 (no matches within group):

```
select Supplier
from table 
group by Supplier
having count(case when Products = 'Toys' then Products end) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it with `NOT EXISTS`

```
select distinct
    supplier 
from 
    table t1
where 
    not exists (select * from table t2 where t1.supplier = t2.supplier and t2.products = 'Toys')
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this here's a couple.  I've found exists and not exists to generally be the fastest but it always depends on indexes and your system.  So look at execution plan for best use in your environment.

using a left join

```
SELECT T.SUPPLIER 
FROM TABLE T
LEFT JOIN TABLE T2 
 on T.Supplier = T2.Supplier
and T2.Products = 'Toys'
where T2.Products is null
```

Using not exists.

```
SELECT supplier
FROM table T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Table A 
                  WHERE T.Supplier = A.Supplier and Products = 'Toys')
```